# Disable Keyboard for UITextfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield, inputview

I'm wondering how to disable the inputview of a UITextfield. Setting `textField.inputView = nil;` or `[textField setInputView:nil]` in ShouldBeginEditing doesn't do anything, and using the `userInteraction` property removes the ability to interact with the field. Ideally, I'd like to remove both the cursor and the keyboard while still being able interact with and switch between textfield methods, using ShouldBeginEditing and ShouldEndEditing. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean "switch between textfield methods"?  What is it you want to do with this UITextField?

Comment: You want your keyborad should not appear ? is that right?

Comment: I've got a couple of UITextfields. Currently I'm using the textFieldShouldBeginEditing and textFieldShouldEndEditing to determine which field is currently active for setting things like a textfield highlight or left/right view images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this:

```
myTextField.inputView = UIView.new; //Empty UIView
```

Setting it to `nil` just means the default keyboard is used.

To get rid of the caret, subclass the UITextField and override `caretRectForPosition`:

```
- (CGRect) caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition*)position
{
    return CGRectZero;
}
```

Comment: This hides the keyboard, but setting the input view to a new view still displays the cursor in the textfield.

Comment: You can't get rid of the cursor, not without subclassing the UITextField. I've edited my answer with how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  return NO;  // Hide both keyboard and blinking cursor.
}
```

or

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
  [textField resignFirstResponder]; // hides keyboard
}
```

Comment: Neither solution really work in this case. I still need the textfield to be active in order to determine what properties to set for each textfield I have in my view.