# xamarin ios textbox focus with no keyboard

Tags: xamarin.ios, textbox

This is my problem.
I need to bring focus to a UItextbox with out the keyboard popping up.
There is a requirement to use a Bluetooth device and when the focus is placed on the UItextbox the keyboard is not needed.

I tried the BecomeFirstResponder() method which does bring focus but the keypad also opens.

Comment: please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It should be hidden automatically when your Bluetooth keyboard connected. See this discussion:[Re-enabling virtual iPad keyboard with paired Bluetooth keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11830/re-enabling-virtual-ipad-keyboard-with-paired-bluetooth-keyboard). And there's a button on Bluetooth keyboard which can hide/open the virtual keyboard. See [this](https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/ipad-bluetooth-keyboard-swiftkey-problem).  Did you connect a Bluetooth keyboard to your iOS device to have a try?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, set the InputView for your TextField to empty using:

```
myTextField.InputView = UIView.New; //Or new UIView();
```

Then set the TextField active by using BecomeFirstResponder()

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18216001/2974780)